# How to add existing string array value with this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

Variable.cs

```
 public string[] CcEmails { get; set; }
```

Mail.cs

```
  EDTO.CcEmails = dr["rsh_ccmail"].ToString().Split(';');
```

here i got two strings eg. xxxx@gmail.com ; yyy@gmail.com

MailProcess.cs

```
dataRPT1=get data from sql
EDTO.CcEmails = new string[dataRPT1.Rows.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataRPT1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        EDTO.CcEmails[i] = dataRPT1.Rows[i]["email_addr"].ToString();
                    }
```

Here i got list of string eg.aaa@gmail.com ......
I am try to add with existing but it add only new values..Anyone could help me..

Comment: If EDTO.CcEmails is an array, why are you using ToString to flatten the array?  Why not just use it as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use union, although that will remove duplicate entries. But to keep all entries you can use Concat on the array.

```
        var emailString = "me@test.com;you@test.com";
        string[] emails = emailString.Split(';');

        string[] emailsFromSQL = new string[3];
        emailsFromSQL[0] = "everyone@test.com";
        emailsFromSQL[1] = "everyone2@test.com";
        emailsFromSQL[2] = "everyone2@test.com";

        //No Duplicates
        var combined = emails.Union(emailsFromSQL).ToArray();

        //Duplicates
        var allCombined = emails.Concat(emailsFromSQL).ToArray();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way of doing this is to create a list, add items to the list, then use string.Join to create the new string.

```
var items = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dataRPT1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    items.Add(dataRPT1.Rows[i]["email_addr"].ToString());
}

EDTO.CcEmails = string.Join(";", items);
```

---

Update after changed question:

If the type of the CcEmails is an array, the last line could be:

```
EDTO.CcEmails = items.ToArray();
```